# After sharing on Facebook, App forced close

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sharing

I am using `sharingIntent` to share a link on apps. When I click the button, it brings sharing window and I share the link correctly. After, sharing process, my app doesnt open and crashes. I am using `intent.getExtras()` to identify image and imageurl. Logcat says the problem is array index is 11, size is equal to zero. However, I dont know how to fix it.

This line gives error, after sharing process completed: `imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls.get(imagePosition), imageView);`

Here is my activity:

```
public class ProductDetail extends Activity {

    static List<String> imageUrls = Data.BIGIMAGE;
    static List<String> productUrl = Data.PRODUCT_URL;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    LinearLayout shareButton;
    int imagePosition;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_itemview);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){ 
            imagePosition = bundle.getInt("imagePosition");
        } 

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        shareButton = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls.get(imagePosition), imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ProductDetail.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("productUrl", productUrl.get(imagePosition));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, productUrl.get(imagePosition));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share With?"));

            }
        });
        }
      }
```

And logcat output:

```
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ProductDetail}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 0
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 0
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at com.example.ProductDetail.onCreate(ProductDetail.java:39)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-12 10:53:45.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

Comment: From which Activity you are getting `imagePosition` ?

Comment: I have MainActivity which has a gridview. When I click an image on gridview, I send imageposition with         this `Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductDetail.class);
         i.putExtra("imagePosition", position);`

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` in `ProductDetail` Activity ?

Comment: and also try it using `StartActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`

Comment: You getting exception after sharing or just when you click on share button ??? Please explain this will help to understand your problem

Comment: No, All codes in `ProductActivity` is above :(

Comment: @Ishrat After I **share** link, Facebook closed normally and then my app crashes.

Comment: you are getting imagePosition is 11 but the imageUrls size 0 @newComer

Comment: Override OnActivityResult in your activity, And use StartActivityForResult, If you still face same error then inside OnActivityResult  do as 
imageUrls = Data.BIGIMAGE;
productUrl = Data.PRODUCT_URL;
Because your imageList becoming empty when you returned to same activity.

Comment: i.putExtra("productUrl", productUrl.get(imagePosition)); this line is getting index out of bound exception as the list productUrl has no item at position imagePosition

Comment: Thx for your effort all guys. As  @ρяσѕρєяK and @Ishrat said that when I write this code `startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share With?"), imagePosition);`, my app doesnt get error.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.BIGIMAGE` is obviously empty. To prove this replace this line

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls.get(imagePosition), imageView);
```

with this

```
if (Data.BIGIMAGE != null && Data.BIGIMAGE.size() > 0) {
  imageLoader.displayImage(Data.BIGIMAGE.get(imagePosition), imageView);
} else {
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Data.BIGIMAGE is null or empty");
}
```

Comment: Hi j0n0. My app doesnt crashes at first time. Imageposition doesnt get null when activity starts at first time. The problem was starting after sharing something on Facebook. I fixed the problem. See above comments. Thx for your effort.